# How to return count of popups opened up by clicking on a mapbox gl map feature?

Tags: javascript, popup, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I’ve a point dataset with overlapping points. For each feature a popup is created automatically. When I click on a point with other overlapping point on it all popups are opened up and it’s messed up. Is there a way to count overlapped points to create some kind of a list for those cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show all clicked features as one popup using below code:

```
//'places' layer 
 map.on('click', 'places', function (e) {

        var list_items = "";
        // e.features.length show the count of clicked features 
        e.features.forEach(function(element) { 
          list_items = list_items +  element.properties.description;
        });

        new mapboxgl.Popup()
            .setLngLat(e.features[0].geometry.coordinates)
            .setHTML("<ul>" + list_items + "</ul>")
            .addTo(map);

       // below is used to stop propagation
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
```